# In PHP Remove several characters from the beginning of a String?

Tags: php, string

I need to find a specic line of text, from a text-file, 
and then copy it to a new text-file:

1: I have a text file with several lines of text, eg:

```
JOHN
MIKE
BEN
*BJAMES
PETE
```

2: So, I read that text-files contents into an array, 
with each line of text, placed into a seperate element of the array.

3: Then I tested each element of the array, 
to find the line that starts with, say: *B  ie:

```
if ( preg_match( "/^\*(B)/",$contents[$a] ) )
```

Which works ok...

4: Then I copy (WRITE) that line of text, to a new text-file.

Q: So how can I remove the '*B' from that line of text, 
BEFORE I WRITE it to the new text-file ?

Answer (score 2):

If you already use `preg_match`, you can modify your regex to get what you want in another variable.

```
if (preg_match('/^\*B(.*)$/', $contens[$a], $matches)
{
    fwrite($targetPointer, $matches[1]);
}
```

After using `preg_match`the variable `$matches` holds the single matches of subparts of the regex enclosed in brackets. So the relevant part of your line ist matched by `(.*)` and saved into `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

This approach writes the lines as the file is read, which is more memory efficient:

```
$sourceFile      = new SplFileObject('source.txt');
$destinationFile = new SplFileObject('destination.txt', 'w+');
foreach (new RegexIterator($sourceFile, '/^\*B.*/') as $filteredLine) {
    $destinationFile->fwrite(
        substr_replace($filteredLine, '', 0, 2)
    );
}
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/st3V4u)

Answer (score 0):

With [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
preg_replace('/^\*B/', '', $content[$a], -1, $count);
if ($count) {
    fwrite($file, $content[$a]);
}
```